# How to place a footer element in a FlatList in a row. React-Native

Tags: react-native, flatlist

I have FlatList with 2 colums, and i want place FooterElement in row

```
export const HabitScreen = ({navigation}) => {
return (
    <View style={{marginTop: 40}}>
        <MyPlansTitle navigation={navigation}/>
        <GeneralView>
            <SubTitle text="Привычки"/>
            <FlatList data={[0,1,2]}
                      extraData={[3]}
                      numColumns={2}
                      columnWrapperStyle={style.row}
                      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                      renderItem={({item}) => (<HabitItem/>)}                            
                      ListFooterComponent={<HabitAddItem />}
        />
        </GeneralView>
    </View>
    )}
```

how to do it?

[Image Flatlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcGE0.png)

Answer (score 0):

add one more element to the data,

```
renderItem={({item, index}) => {
          if (index+1 == data.length){
            return <Text>Footer</Text>
          }
          return <Text>{item}</Text>
        }}
```